# Trying to create a snapshot of an index, status is "empty_store"

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I am using ElasticSearch 7.17.

I am trying to create a snapshot of an index:
(I know I shouldn't have a single shard, but for now, that's how it is) :

```
$ curl -s -k  "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices"
yellow open myIndex vVr6ojDCQTi9ASOUGkkRBA 1 1 679161903 0 140.8gb 140.8gb
```

I have already registered an S3 bucket for snapshots, which I named `backups`.

I ran the following command:

```
$ curl -s -k -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/backups/myIndex?pretty&wait_for_completion=false" -H "content-type:application/json" -d'{"indices": "myIndex"}'
{
  "accepted" : true
}
```

Now, I want to have a look at the progress of that backup's upload :

```
$ curl -s -k  "http://localhost:9200/_cat/snapshots/backups/myIndex"
myIndex  IN_PROGRESS 1676385605 14:40:05 0          00:00:00  8.6m 1 0 0 0

$ curl -s -k  "http://localhost:9200/_cat/recovery"
myIndex 0 37ms empty_store    done n/a n/a 172.24.0.3 7529c7447620 n/a n/a 0 0 0.0%   0 0 0 0.0%   0    0 0 100.0%
```

It's been in this state, with no change, for the past  1 hour.

I don't understand why 0 bytes are transfered. Am I missing something obvious ?
I don't know what `empty_store` refers to - shouldn't it be `existing_store` ?

Comment: You are not missing anything obvious, and it's too early to determine if there is an issue with the data transfer

Comment: It's been in that state for 6 hours now...

Comment: The index is 140.8gb so it probably takes a bit of time. What's the status of the snapshot progress?

Comment: `curl -s -k  "http://localhost:9200/_cat/snapshots/backups/myIndex"` returns `myIndex IN_PROGRESS 1676385605 14:40:05 0          00:00:00 29.2m 1 0 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

Other people were right - it just took its time.

The snapshot ended in `"SUCCESS"` status, but the repository remains in `empty_store`.